# How to make a button in a custom control to fire onClick event and have it handled in the main form where the custom control resides?

Tags: c#

In C#, I created a custom control which inherits from UserControl, and added a button btnInTrayMap to the custom control. 
Then I added the custom control to the main form. The main form has another button for comparison of their behaviours.
What I observed is the button on the main form works fine when clicked. However, the button btnInTrayMap which resides in the custom control does not respond at all when it is clicked.

I have the following code for the button in the custom control:

```
public partial class TrayMap : UserControl
{                      
    public TrayMap()
    {                                    
        InitializeComponent();               
    }        

    public event EventHandler MyCustomClickEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyCustomClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (MyCustomClickEvent != null)
            MyCustomClickEvent(this, e);
    }

    private void btnInTrayMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        OnMyCustomClickEvent(sender, EventArgs.Empty);            
    } 
}
```

I believe btnTrayMap.Click's event handler in TrayMap.designer.cs may have caused the problem:

```
this.btnInTrayMap.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnInTrayMap_Click);
```

In the main form, I have the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnInForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test Button In Form", "btnInForm Button Clicked", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

    public void MyCustomClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show("Test Button In TrayMap", button.Text + " Button Clicked", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to set event delegation such that the MyCustomClickEvent method in the main form will be executed when the button btnInTrayMap is clicked.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you registered `MyCustomClickEvent` in main form ??

Comment: How do I register MyCustomClickEvent in the main form?

Comment: Please show an example. Thank you.

Comment: Show your code of user control of main page.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include all the code

Comment: What is the name of user control in your main form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not register your event in your main form. Try this way.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        trayMap.MyCustomClickEvent += MyCustomClickEvent;  // i'm assuming trayMap is the name of user control in main form.
    }

    private void btnInForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test Button In Form", "btnInForm Button Clicked", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

    private void MyCustomClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show("Test Button In TrayMap", button.Text + " Button Clicked", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```